# Error al crear .zip

Tags: c#, zip

Estoy creando un `zip`, con ciertos archivos, y haciendo que este se cree
en cierta direccion, tengo lo siguiente:

```
string  path = @"direccion de guardado";

//estoy creando el nombre del zip con la fecha actual
string pathZip = path + "\\" + fecha_actual.Month.ToString() + "-" + fecha_actual.Day.ToString() + "-" + fecha_actual.Year + ".zip";

//aqui es donde se realiza el zip y lo guarda en la direccion indicada.
 string upload = ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(path, pathZip);
```

el problema que tengo actualmente es que me sale el siguiente mensaje:

> string path cannot implicitly convert type void to string (tambien en
> pathZip sucede lo mismo)

Como puedo solucionar este error?

Comment: si path es direccion de guardado, no es una ruta valida.. sera eso?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te ocurre es que la funcion CreateFromDirectory es void es decir no retorna nada y lo estas intentando almacenar y emplear en una variable por eso te da el error [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.createfromdirectory?view=netcore-3.1)

```
string startPath = @".\start";
string zipPath = @".\result.zip";
string extractPath = @".\extract";

    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);

    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

te dejo otro link donde aplica el funcionamiento completo de zipFile [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files)